# Setting publish rights to Azure website

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-web-app-service

I have multiple developers in my team and I'd like to control who has publish rights to my Azure Website.

We're using Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 CTP for developing this ASP.NET MVC site. I want to make sure Developer A and B can publish to the site but NOT Developer C.

I'd appreciate some pointers on how to manage publish rights to Azure Websites.

Comment: Thank you for your response. if you submit it as an answer, I can accept it as such so that you get credit for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft just added RBAC functionality for website deployments:

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/01/05/rbac-and-azure-websites-publishing/